# Angularjs. How to get a global jquery object and other (jQuery plugin / Angularjs things!) ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, youtube, mediaelement.js

I want to use http://mediaelementjs.com/ to play multiple youtube video in my app. So i have created a directive who load mediaelementjs :

**Directives**

```
.directive('mediaelement', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).mediaelementplayer();
        }
    }
})
```

and i have my player like that :

**Player**

```
<video id="player" controls width="374px" height="301px" type="video/youtube" src="{{currentMusic}}" youtube>
```

Because it's a youtube video medialementjs use flash.

**First Problem**

`currentMusic` is initialized only later and when i change `currentMusic` the DOM is correctly modify but mediaelementjs don't change the source and when i click play nothing play because the source on the flash object is still `{{currentMusic}}` (not binded)

but if i put directly a youtube source in video src everything is ok.

and if i put a value in `currentMusic` when my app load and then i wait 2 sec to create mediaelementjs object everything is ok too !

Why ?

**Second Problem**

If i delete my first mediaelementjs object after a video have been play then i change currentMusic and then i create a new medialementjs object the source is correctly change.

so i have to use setSrc()

and so i would like to change source of the video when i click on a link in an other part of my app. 
but how can i get my mediaelement object ?

**So how make a list of youtube video play with angularjs and mediaelementjs ?**

i really hope i'm clear... i spend two days trying to undestand thats happening and make things work but i fail...

Source :
[How do I get mediaelement.js player state (paused, volume, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689533/how-do-i-get-mediaelement-js-player-state-paused-volume-etc)

http://johndyer.name/html5-video-wrapper-for-youtube-and-vimeo-api-mediaelement-js/

[media player object from directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616519/media-player-object-from-directive/21447338#21447338)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put inside **$observe** your directive:

```
attrs.$observe('src', function(src) {
      $(element).mediaelementplayer();
 });
```

so you will init your plugin each time after SRC is changed

second issue has different solutions, for example using scope/service:

```
scope.mediaObject = $(element).mediaelementplayer();
```

**UPD:**

I've read docs for MediaElementPlayer, so should be pretty simple:

```
attrs.$observe('src', function(src) {
    $(element).mediaelementplayer().setSrc(src);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when i do that it seems like the previous medialementjs object is not replace by the new one. so the video haven't any source to play. but the src is correctly change and if i put a console.log in attrs.$observe i see the console.log. any idea ?

Comment: ya, sure
callback param syntax is so -
function(newValue, oldVAlue)